# Aggregate PostgreSQL rows with same column value into nested JSON structure

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a single table in a Postgres database with properties for `city` and `name`, like so:

| city | name |
| --- | --- |
| NYC | John |
| NYC | Allie |
| Phoenix | Dave |
| Phoenix | Beatrice |
| LA | Michael |

(There are more columns in the table, but they're unimportant for this question.)

I would like to construct a query that returns the names, grouped by city, as a JSON object. Like so:

```json
{
  "LA": ["Michael"],
  "NYC": ["Allie", "John"],
  "Phoenix": ["Beatrice", "Dave"]
}
```

Or similar. Doesn't have to be that exact structure, but you get the idea. I want to arrange this into a hierarchical structure organized by city. Both city names and person names within the array values should be sorted alphabetically.

I've gotten pieces of this, but as a SQL neophyte I'm struggling to wrap my head around structuring a hierarchical query like this. Please help! :)

I can get a single ordered JSON array of names filtered by city:

```
select json_agg(name order by name asc) from my_table where city = 'NYC'
```

and I know I will probably have to alias that query for use in a parent query, like:

```
with names as (select ...)
```

but I'm not sure where to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object( city, json_agg( name )) AS result
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY city
WHERE city = 'NYC' ORDER BY name ASC;
```

---

The function `jsonb_build_object` builds a JSON object as:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(1, 'a', true, row(2, 'b', false));
```

Result:

```
{"1": "a", "true": {"f1": 2, "f2": "b", "f3": false}}
```

---

The function `json_build_array` builds a JSON array as:

```
SELECT json_build_array(1, 'a', true, row(2, 'b', false));
```

Result:

```
[1, "a", true, {"f1":2,"f2":"b","f3":false}]
```